# Run a Youtube Video from a time to another and autoplay with loop feature

Tags: loops, video, youtube, html5-video, autoplay

I am not a coder but understand little bit of code language. I wanted to play a video from YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSxLUha7AZY) which has more than 1 hour long time.

I just need to play the video from **5:50 (350 s)** to **42:15 (2529 s)** and loop the video over and over again automatically.

Can someone guide me how should I write the codes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this website](https://looptube.io/) to loop your youtube video with a specific range.

Alternatively, you can download the video then crop your range.

Comment: Thank you for the link attached. Nice website.